# How to delete line above/below cursor, but not current line?

Tags: key-bindings, cursor-movement, normal-mode

Is there a command for deleting line (or n lines) above current one? Above = current not included.

I.e., is there an alternative to <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> which doesn't delete current line? Similar to how <kbd>o</kbd>/<kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>p</kbd>/<kbd>P</kbd> work, but with deletion.

Currently, I'm doing <kbd>k</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>, which moves cursor one line up and deletes it. I could do `nnoremap <Leader>d kdd` and `nnoremap <Leader>D jdd-`, but having an alternative which doesn't move the cursor seems like a better option. Is there such?

Comment: If your problem is that your mappings move the cursor why don't you do `nnoremap <Leader>d kddj` and `nnoremap <Leader>D jddk`?

Comment: Using either `kddj` or `jddk`, column position is not preserved. I'm not saying it's a big problem, but it's annoying.

For the record, `kddj` moves cursor 1 line below original position. And `jdd-` seems like a better alternative to `jddk` because at least I'm returning to first non white space character. If line below the one I want deleted is empty, I'm left at the beginning of the line.

Comment: How about using makdd`a for your map? Sets a mark and returns to it afterwards... you might want to change it to a lesser used character though.

Comment: @PhilippFrank Or I can use `` to get the cursor back and not occupy a register (not that I use any :) ).

Comment: No that doesn't work, k is not a jump, so you cannot go back using ``.

Comment: You're right. I was trying `` with `:-d`, not with `kdd`.

Comment: And :-d induces a jump? Interesting, I did not know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
:-d
```

cuts the line above the current line.

---

```
:-5d
```

cuts the 5th line above the current line (but moves the cursor).

---

```
:-5,-d
```

cuts the 5 lines above the current line.

---

```
:+,+5d
```

cuts the 5 lines below the current line.

Comment: That still moves the cursor, though.

Comment: You can't avoid moving the cursor. The best you can do is move the cursor *and move it back*.

Comment: Thank you! This kind of "vim way" is what I was looking for. I'm going to use this in combination with `` to get the cursor back where it was.

Answer (score 7):

If we use the small delete register "-, we can restore the cursor position after deleting above n lines.

For example, <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> deletes above 1 line and restores the cursor back where it was.

1. <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> deletes characters from the cursor to the first character of the line. Since <kbd>0</kbd> is an exclusive motion, the character under the cursor is not deleted. And the deleted characters are put into the small delete regsiter "-.
2. <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> deletes above 1 line. This will leave the current line, because <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> is not linewise and exclusive.
3. <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> puts the text from the small delete register "-.

It is a sort of hack. But if you are looking for non-ex commands, consider using it.

Comment: Nice solution! Although I think you want `"-P` not `"-p`. The latter messes up the text a little bit.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem You're right. I corrected the answer. Thank you for pointing out it.

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT** I didn't know the built-in features suggested by @Romainl in his answer: of course the `-d` and `+d` method should be prefered as it is way simpler than adding functions to your `.vimrc`

Maybe adding something like that to your `.vimrc` could be what you want:

```
function! DeleteOver()
   let save_cursor = getpos(".")
   normal k
   normal dd
   call setpos(".", save_cursor)
   normal k
endfunction

function! DeleteUnder()
   let save_cursor = getpos(".")
   normal j
   normal dd
   call setpos(".", save_cursor)
endfunction
```

These functions delete the line under or the line over the current one and go back to the position before the deletion.

For the function `DeleteOver()` we need to go up one line with `normal k` after the deletion because the deletion change the number of the original line which doesn't happend with `DeleteUnder()`

You can also add this to your `.vimrc`

```
nnoremap <Leader>d :call DeleteOver()<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>D :call DeleteUnder()<CR>
```

To create the mappings calling the functions.

Comment: An alternative to saving/restoring the cursor position is to unset/restore the `nostartofline` option.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you'll improve your workflow if don't fear to ... jump :)

Example:

```
This is where cursor initially is: _.

[Some other stuff you want to keep/skip ...]

I want to delete these lines.
I want to delete these lines.
I want to delete these lines.
I want to delete these lines.
I want to delete these lines.
```

Your actions (normal mode, cursor is on `_`): `/I want` `Enter` `5dd` `Ctrl-o`. That's it.

Of course, [romainl](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/54/romainl) answer is the best if all you want to delete whole lines, and you can count their offset easily (using relative linenumbers for example). The above is a more generic way to "act": go there, using something that counts as a jump: this means you can always jump back, after you modify the text.

For example, if you use absolute line numbers, you can replace the `/I want` `Enter` with something like `78gg` or `78G` to jump directly at that line number.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [ms-kim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/8031/ms-kim) solution I have developed a slightly different variation that saves col postion.

```
function! DeleteLineAbove()
    if line('.') == 1
        echom "You are at the first line!"
        return
    endif
    let l:colsave = col(".")
    exec  "normal! kdd"
    call cursor(line("."), l:colsave)
endfunction
nnoremap <Leader>k :call DeleteLineAbove()<CR>
```

OBS: I have also used [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34370951/2571881) as reference.

Comment: Do you mean @statox rather than @MS.Kim?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to delete duplicate lines throughout the whole file, just do the following:

```
:g/any part of the string/d
```

Example:

In command mode

```
:g/I want to delete/d
```

If you just want a list of the string(s) initially:

```
:g/I want to delete/p
```

Comment: I'm not really sure how this answers the asked question?